# Can Python server code be read?

Tags: python, websocket, server

I am working on a Python WebSocket server. I initiate it by running the `python server.py` command in Terminal. After this, the server runs fine and actually pretty well for what I'm using it for. The server runs on port 8000.

My question is, if I keep the server.py file outside of my localhost directory or any sub-directory, can the Python file be read and the code viewed by anyone else?

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on the permissions of the directory and the file.

Comment: @aaron_world_traveler So if I have a directory with read, write, and execute off, then the Python file can't be viewed, but it can be executed still through Terminal?

Comment: That's correct.  It's still executable via `python server.py`, just not by doing something like putting a hashbang in the file and doing `./server.py`.

Comment: So turning off all those permissions effectively blocks the code from being viewed by anyone without physical access to the computer, but still allows it to be executed by python server.py. Correct?

Comment: Yes, practically speaking.  There's always some possibility that an attacker could gain root access to the machine and remotely view the code...but then that would be the least of your worries.

Comment: @aaron_world_traveler Well thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give a definite yes or no answer, because there are a million ways in which your server may expose the .py file. The crucial point is though, that your server needs to actively expose the file to the outside world. A computer with no network-enabled services running does not expose anything on the network, period. Only physical access to the computer would allow you access to the file.

From this absolute point, it's a slow erosion of security with every additional service that offers a network component. Your Python server itself (presumably) doesn't expose its own source code; it only offers the services it's programmed to offer. However, you may have other servers running on the machine which actively do offer the file for download, or perhaps can be tricked into doing so. That's where an absolute "No" is hard to give, because one would need to run a full audit of your machine to be able to give a definitive answer.

Suffice it to say that a *properly configured server* without gaping security holes will not enable users to download the underlying source code through the network.

Comment: Correct, the Python file does not expose any source code. The only other server on the machine would be Apache. Let's say localhost is /WebServer/documents. The public sees this directory when I type in the public IP address. However, the Python file is stored and executed in /WebServer/servers. Hopefully this explained the structure a little bit better.

Comment: If Apache is correctly configured to ***not*** serve files from /WebServer/servers, then there should be no issue. Note that there can still be secondary issues with some executable inside /WebServer/documents (say, a PHP file) accepting arbitrary paths from requests and reading and outputting your .py file (reading file system content from unverified user provided paths). There may also be tertiary issues where a user may be able to upload code which when executed can read arbitrary locations (vulnerability to backdoor installations)...

Comment: Do you have an unpatched Wordpress installation on that server? You're probably already pwned... Again, without a full audit, nobody can give you a clean bill of health. :)

Comment: No, WordPress is not installed nor ever will be. Not a single file in the Apache server gives the user any ability to upload or execute their own code. The server is hosting a REST API to be used by its iOS counterpart.

Comment: That's assuming there are no vulnerabilities in that REST server that could be exploited... Every single line of code running on your server is a potential security vulnerability... :)

Comment: You mean in the API functions?

Comment: Yes. *Anything* that receives and sends data over the network is a ***potential*** security vulnerability. That includes a REST API.

Comment: Yah, I understand that. However I'm confident the REST API does not give any access whatsoever to the Python file or any other directories.

Comment: Short of paying a pentester, that's the best you'll get then... :)